# How do I know what is my public key and the private key in RSA algorithm?

Tags: python

I made program that encrypts the data in a text file, but I don't really understand a few things.

I use the `RSA` encryption algorithm, with the `pycryptodome` package.

The first thing I don't understand is: `PKCS1_OAEP`, `RSA` is asymmetric encryption, so why we need another `RSA`-based algorithm? - The other thing I don't understand is how I recognize whats my `public key` and whats my `private key`, people say that - `RSA.generate()` creates both `public` and `private key`, but how do I see them both? The third thing I don't understand is what `new` means when I put the key argument to it, what does `new` do?

```
import os
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

desktop = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')
key = RSA.generate(2048) # 2048 bit key
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

if os.path.exists(os.path.join(desktop, 'newfile.txt')):
    with open(os.path.join(desktop, 'newfile.txt'), 'rb') as f:
        if not f.readable():
            pass
        else:
            plainText = f.read()
            cipherText = cipher.encrypt(plainText)
            print(f'Encrypted Text: {cipherText}')
else:
    print('File is not exists!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I want to put it in layman's terms, You need a random generated `key` to create an `RSA` public/private key pair. So, `key = RSA.generate(2048)` is generating a random key so you can use it to create a `new` `PKCS1_OAEP` public/private key pair.

For the other part of your question where you asked about accessing your public/private keys, you can use a code like this:

```py
key = RSA.generate(2048)
private_key = key.export_key()
file_out = open("private.pem", "wb")
file_out.write(private_key)

public_key = key.publickey().export_key()
file_out = open("receiver.pem", "wb")
file_out.write(public_key)
```

> Quoted from [documentation](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/examples.html#generate-public-key-and-private-key)

Comment: Hey, from your answer, I still don't really understand what `PKCS1_OAEP.new()` does.

Comment: `PKCS1_OAEP.new()` Is only for the encryption part ?

Comment: It is creating the public/private key pair, using the random `key` generated in the previous line.

Comment: Hey, one more question, If I want to share with someone for example, my files, I need to send to him my private key to decrypt it ?

Comment: Encryption is done using the `public key` and `private key` is used for decryption. If you want to send an encrypted message to someone else, you should use "their" public key to encrypt the message. While "they" are holding their private keys safe, they will be able to decrypt your message. If you were to provide a private key whenever you want to transmit some "encrypted" message, the whole thing would not make any sense then.